# 2 APIs in one c# WebApi project

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I work on single page app project with API, which is located under mydomain.com/api/ url. Now I need to have separate API for other purpose e.g. mydomain.com/exchangebox/api/.

1. Is it possible to have both APIs controllers in same WebApi project?
2. If so, how the application knows which controller to use, if I request /api/person/ or /exchangebox/api/person?

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your questions.. specifically:

> 1) Is it possible to have both APIs controllers in same WebApi project?

Yes. It is.

> 2) If so, how the application knows which controller to use, if I request /api/person/ or /exchangebox/api/person?

Routes. MVC and WebAPI is based on routing. I would suggest you read a tutorial or two on what Routes are and how they work.

For example, this tutorial on the ASP.NET website: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api